# Why does my URL work locally, but not externally? Setup with Pi-Hole as local DNS and Apache reverse proxy to redirect to different service ports

Tags: linux, dns, apache-http-server, reverse-proxy, pihole

I have a Pi-Hole and an Apache2 reverse proxy on a Raspberry Pi installed in my local network. My router uses this Pi-Hole as its DNS. Pi-Hole is configured as installed fresh, with the exception of local DNS entries that resolve my Domain to the Pi's IP address.

The Pi's local IP is 192.168.0.44.

The backend server's local IP is 192.168.0.43 and it has three services running on different ports.

Pi-Hole local DNS entries:

```
subdomain1.domain.net -> 192.168.0.44
subdomain2.domain.net -> 192.168.0.44
subdomain3.domain.net -> 192.168.0.44
```

Apache2 reverse proxy.conf also running on the Raspberry Pi

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain1.domain.net

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.43:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.43:80/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain2.domain.net

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.43:8096/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.43:8096/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName subdomain2.domain.net

        ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.43:666/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.43:666/
</VirtualHost>
```

My domain is registered through Google and I have a DNS entry there:

```
subdomain1.domain.net -> my static external IP
```

Now, to my problem:

When I try to connect to one of my services using "subdomain1.domain.net" in my **local** network, it resolves correctly to the reverse proxy running on 192.168.0.44 listening on port 80, which then redirects it to 192.168.0.43:80 or *:8096, depending on the URL given. This works for all my services **locally**.

Externally tho, it just does not connect. I have forwarded port 80 to 192.168.0.44 in my router, which is the IP of my Raspberry Pi.

Previously, before I installed Pi-Hole and did not have a reverse proxy set up, I connected to my services using "URL":port when I was outside my network, but I firstly wanted to make that work in local LAN, without using IPs, and secondly for it to work with subdomains, without also having to specify ports, hence the reverse proxy.

Any suggestions or ideas? I have been googling this forever now and I might just ditch this whole idea and just connect using my domain and port if this doesn't work.Thanks to everyone in advance for any input!!!

Comment: I'd check the nginx logs, see if anything obvious there - sorry, apache logs (not sure why I said nginx)